# How to match a fixed string with digits with javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

The String is - `Success0` or `Success7` or any digit.I tried with -

```
console.log(str.match("Success"+/\d/));
```

But it is logging `null`. Any help?

Comment: What strings are your trying to match?

Comment: You cannot add a regex to a string.

Comment: @elclanrs then how can i match them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex in `.match()` isnt right.

Do:

```js
var str = "Success123";

alert(str.match(/^Success\d+$/)); // returns the string if it is a match, otherwise null
```

---

Note that if you are just testing the string if it has `Success` at the begining, you should be using `.test()`. `.match()` takes a toll on the browser as compared to  `.test()`.

```js
var str = "Success123";

alert(/^Success\d+$/.test(str)); // returns true/false
```

---

Regex `/^Success\d+$/` [explained here](https://www.regex101.com/r/xM6bN5/1).

Readup:

- [`.test()` | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)
- [`.match()` | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: @sgt I am glad it helped. Please upvote and mark this answer as accepted if you think it is upto the mark.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
str.match(/Success\d+/)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are having **numbers** and it's the whole string :

`str.match(/^Success\d+$/)`

Ir you want to build up your regex :

```
var r= new RegExp("^Success"+'\\d+$')
console.log(r.test('Success232'));
```